# Pusher/Laravel notification when the user is offline

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I'm working on a specific CRM application and I'm trying to send notifications with pusher and I had some issues: the user has to be connected to receive notifications.

This is my code for sending notifications when trying to add some users to a specific group:

```
$pusher = \App::make('pusher');

//send Pusher notififation to 'user-id' channel
$pusher->trigger( $user_to_add->channel_id , 'add-group',
                  array('text' => Auth::user()->name . ' added you to the group : ' . 
                        '<a href="group/'.$group->id .'">' . $group->name . '</a>') );
```

This is my code for reading the notifications:

```
<script>
// pusher log to console.
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

// here is pusher client side code.
var pusher = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}", {
  encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('<?php  echo Auth::user()->channel_id ; ?>' );

channel.bind('add-group', function(data) {
$('.notification-bar').append(
  '<li>' +
    '<div class="md-list-addon-element"> <span class="md-user-letters md-bg-cyan">  </span> </div> '+

    '<div class="md-list-content">' +
      '<span class="md-list-heading">'+
        data.text+
      '</span>'+

    '</div>'+
  ' </li>'
  );
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine while the user is online. But when he's offline he doesn't receive anything.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. You want them to receive pusher notifications when they are not online?

Comment: No, when the notification is sent and the user is offline, when he login he don't find the notification.

Comment: That's the nature of Pusher. It pushes to the users browser directly. If the browser is not online it won't be listening to the channel you subscribe the user to. In other words, if the user is not online they are not subscribed, thus, will not receive the notification.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understood it in a wrong way. Can you give me a solution for a laravel notifications system ?

Comment: You will have to store the events yourself in a database, and when a user reconnects, you should send them all the events since the last even that they received through Pusher.

Comment: @JrbYoussef take a look at Laravel's Notifications provider. This will allow you to create notifications, and broadcast them using the Broadcast driver to Pusher. Laravel has the ability to do everything you want to do already. The Notifications provider will save notifications in the database if configured to do so.

Comment: Yes i saw it yesterday i'm reading the documentation. Thank you mate.